# How can I share code between my application and my service?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

For the sake of this question, I've replaced some logic with comments and simplified the layous. But the main purpose of the question should be the same.

So I have an activity view with a button and a textview.

`layout_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code behind
`MainActivity.java`

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // retrieve data from internet and display in the textview
            findViewById(R.id.textView).setText(response);
        }
    });
```

Now with [this library](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/springy-heads), I can display the `layout_main` with a *service* in a floating window outside of the activity. See demo gif on the github page. With another button on my xml I start the service.

```
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
```

[Demo code](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/springy-heads/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/flipkart/springyheads/demo/ChatHeadService.java) from the github page:

`MyService.java`

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManagerContainer = new WindowManagerContainer(this);
    chatHeadManager = new DefaultChatHeadManager<String>(this, windowManagerContainer);
    chatHeadManager.setViewAdapter(new ChatHeadViewAdapter<String>() {

        @Override
        public View attachView(String key, ChatHead chatHead, ViewGroup parent) {
            View cachedView = viewCache.get(key);
            if (cachedView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_main, parent, false);
                // 'problem' here
                cachedView = view;
                viewCache.put(key, view);
            }
            parent.addView(cachedView);
            return cachedView;
        }
...
```

But now the problem is, I have to create duplicate code in the service to handle the network requests and display the text. It is basically the same code in the activity.

So my question is, can I somehow share the 'code-behind' to use for my activity and my service or do I have to create a duplicate of the code from my activity?

Comment: Um, you can create another Java class, put the code there, and use an instance of that Java class from both your activity and your service.

Comment: Attaching listeners to buttons, for example, would still require to do it in both classes right?

Comment: You can pass the `Linearlayout` representing your inflated layout to some common Java class that handles both scenarios. Give your `LinearLayout` an `id`, so you can obtain it after `setContentView()` in the activity.

Comment: Sounds like a feasible solution, will try it out and post results here later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can indeed just put my view as a paramater of a class to handle both views there

For my activity:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout_main, null);
setContentView(view);
new ViewHandler(MainActivity.this, view);
...
```

For my service:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_main, false);
new ViewHandler(MyService.this, view);
```

The ViewHandler:

```
public ViewHandler(Context context, View view) {
    super(context, view);
    // get ids from the view and attach handlers or do other things with it
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    ....
```